# jQuery not animating links

Tags: jquery, url, jquery-animate

I am trying to get the fade effect of my image slider plugin to work correctly with links.

At the moment the slider fades correctly however the links are failing to change. The first image is supposed to link to Google.com & the second link is supposed to link to Hotmail.com however both of them are linking to Hotmail.com only (the link for the last image; this is the case no matter how many images you use).

To achieve the fade I am using `.animate({opacity:0}})` & 1, etc. Here are the lines that seem to effect the animation (72, 215 & 216 respectively):

```
$(this.slides).css('opacity',0).eq(this.currentNo).css('opacity',1);

$(this.slides).stop().animate({opacity:0}, {
        duration: this.settings.duration,
        easing:this.settings.easing
} );
$(this.slides).eq(index).stop().animate( {opacity:1}, {
        duration: this.settings.duration,
        easing:this.settings.easing
} );
```

**Source:** http://pastebin.com/9JwaM9tg

**Test site:** http://matthewruddy.com/demo

Thanks to anyone who can help me out. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only setting the opacity of the `li` so while it is not visible it is still displayed when the opacity reaches 0 you should set `display: none` so that the `li` is completely hidden this should then allow the currently visible image to link properly.

```
$(this.slides).css({'opacity':0, 'display':'none'}).eq(this.currentNo).css({'opacity':1, 'display':'block'});

$(this.slides).stop().animate({opacity:0}, {
    duration: this.settings.duration,
    easing:this.settings.easing,
    complete:function(){
        $(this).css({'display':'none'});
    }
});

$(this.slides).eq(index).stop().css('display','block').animate( {opacity:1}, {
    duration: this.settings.duration,
    easing:this.settings.easing
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it! You do not understand how long I've been trying to figure out this problem. Spent weeks learning jQuery as a result. Thanks again!